# KornShell SQL script parser -- parallel execution from ksh

Tags: sql, shell, parsing, parallel-processing, ksh

I am trying to run bunch of scripts in parallel in KornShell (ksh) co-processes. Some of these scripts contain many DDL statements. Those DDL statements are identified to be independent and work against different (and large/expensive eg: 35 million rows and above) database objects. In order to run them in parallel, I am considering to create separate sub-scripts with each DDL statement - so that I can say: SQL*Plus  - that is going to be many :( -- resulting too many read and write -- because it is a batch process, time required is not too critical but (may still lead to thrashing in this single disk-parallel execution environment)..

I still do not like the idea of physical script proliferation..wonder if there is a way to to invoke a parser from ksh so that I can extract out each DDL / DML or any other statements from a reasonably large script file and programmatically execute them in background processes.. any thoughts?

Comment: yes it's possible. Look for ksh examples with `while read line ; do .... ; done < file`. You'll also want to read up on backgrounding tasks with a trailing '&' char on a command line. Do some tests and when you get stuck, post a new question with sample input, required output/action, code, current output and error msgs, and a description of why the current output is wrong. If you've told your boss it will be done in a 3 days, it's time to start resetting those expectations, what you propose is not something that will happen overnight! ;-) Good luck.

Comment: search here for  `[ksh] OR [bash] background`. there are way more questions about [bash] than [ksh], but bash and ksh are 95% similar, most of what you'll read about backgrounding processes in bash will apply to ksh. ( Oh, incidentally, if you're doing ksh on AIX or solaris, you'll be using the ksh88 by default. Look around to find out where the 'new' ksh might be installed.). Again, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Shellter -- my question was more about 'parsing' than about the Korn / control structures itself. thanks anyway.

Comment: It's almost always a good idea to pose a question with 1. minimal sample data that covers cases you expect to process, 2. required output given that input, 3. code you have tried so far, even just psuedo-code, 4. results you are getting and exact error messages. 5 why the current output is wrong and questions about how you want to fix it. If you can provide some detail, we may be able to help you. Good luck.

Comment: input: single .sql file with many DDL,,,
output: extract out DDL,,,  
my thoughts: possibly need a good parser?!,,,

thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work:

```
cat DDL_statements | parallel -j20 --pipe -N 10 sql oracle://scott:tiger@server
```

This assumes the DDL_statements are 1 line long (if they are not 1 line long, give a few examples). It runs 20 jobs in parallel and starts them in blocks of 10 statements.

It uses GNU Parallel (and GNU sql - part of GNU Parallel).